# Error : Identifier 'q' is not readable in architecture of T Flip Flop

Tags: vhdl, flip-flop

I am trying to model a T Flip Flop using VHDL.

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
entity tff is
    port (
        clk: std_logic;
        t: in bit;
        q: out bit;
        qbar: out bit);
end tff;

architecture tff_arch of tff is
begin
    process(clk)
    begin
        if (clk = '1' and t = '1')
        then
            q <= not q;
            qbar <= not qbar;
        end if;
    end process;
end tff_arch;
```

But the error i am getting is

```
Error: CSVHDL0168: tff.vhdl: (line 17): Identifier 'q' is not readable
Error: CSVHDL0168: tff.vhdl: (line 18): Identifier 'qbar' is not readable
```

The reason of error i think is, i am using "not q", when q has not been initialized. Correct me here, if i am wrong.

And what to do to get around this problem? I have modeled D Flip flop and its test bench waveform correctly using Symphony EDA free version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`q` is an output of the entity.

You can't read an output. It's that simple.

You need an internal version that you use for the feedback loop, and then `q <= local_q`;

Comment: oh! right, q should be a inout bit. doing this solved the problem.

Comment: No, it's not an inout, because you can't send a value in on this port. It's an output. If you change it to an inout you're changing how other blocks in the design view this port. You just need a local intermediate signal.

Answer (score 3):

In the old days you couldn't read an output, so you had to either:

- make it an `inout` (which is a bit unpleasant as you are fudging the direction you really mean, just so you can read it) - this works, but is not widely used in industry (as far as I'm aware)
- make it a `buffer`, but that had downsides (prior to VHDL-2002) in that you have to make all the rest of the hierarchy of that signal driven by `buffer`s.  Almost never used in my experience.
- use and intermediate `signal` (which you *can* read) and then use an assignment to set the output to the value of that signal.  This is the idiomatic way of doing it amongst practising engineers.

Since VHDL-2008 you *can* read output ports (although the stated intention of this is for it only to be used for verification purposes).  You'll probably need a tool switch to enable VHDL-2008 mode.  (And it may be that your particular simulator/synthesiser still doesn't support VHDL-2008, which shows the staggering pace of development in the EDA tools world!)

Comment: shouldn't inout be a natural choice for flip flops at least?

Comment: The problem is that using inout tends to imply to synthesisers that they should be a tristate driver in.  You don't want or need *that*.  inout works, but feels hacky.  Intermediate signals are the purist way (which is very widely used in industry).  I'll update the answer a bit

Answer (score 0):

Can't remember VHDL very well, but this might give you a clue:

The problem is that `q` is only a signal out of your entity, so there is nothing to access when you try to read it.

So, to not solve your homework, think of it this way:

Either you need to have `q` as an input in order to access it (probably not what you want) or you need to store `q` (or at least next value of `q`) internally. This can be done by specifying `q` (or `q_next`) as a `signal` in the `architecture` part. For example:

```
architecture tff_arch of tff is
  signal q_next: std_logic;
begin
```

and so on. The same goes for your `qbar` signal.